# How to run GDAL vector (OGR) tools from inside QGIS?

Tags: qgis, gdal, ogr

I want fingertip access to the GDAL/OGR tools, particularly **ogrinfo**, from the main QGIS screen.

I currently run **ogrinfo.exe** in a DOS shell but this seems clumsy.

Installing the GDAL Tools plugin only accesses the raster tools. (The User Guide confirms this.)

But in my Windows QGIS folder there is a file:

```
 C:\Program Files\QGIS283\apps\qgis-ltr\python\plugins\processing\algs\gdal\ogrinfo.py
```

Does this perhaps somehow let me run **ogrinfo** from the Python console?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you downloaded and installed QGIS through the OSGeo4W Network Installer you will have access to the [QGIS Processing Framework](http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing/index.html). Among other algorithm providers this will provide you access to the GDAL/OGR Provider which includes (under OGR miscellaneous) the [Information](http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/ogr_miscellaneous.html#information) tool (which is `ogrinfo`). The results will be output to a temporary HTML file.

If you do want to access it from the Python console you can run the algorithm from there as well, for example:

```python
>>> lyr = iface.activeLayer()
>>> import processing
>>> processing.runalg('gdalogr:information', lyr, None)
{'OUTPUT': u'/var/folders/pd/ydjvghhj0xx7jr0_0bzz85n80000gn/T/processing/6feb7dc9a3894ed5a5276a3d48f94180/OUTPUT.html'}
```

Note that you still have to open the HTML file yourself, so it may be easier to just use the processing GUI. Or you could try:

```python
>>> import os
>>> os.startfile(processing.runalg('gdalogr:information', lyr, None)["OUTPUT"])
```

Comment: This was a preposterously useful answer, pointing me to the 'Processing Framework' chapter of the User Guide which greatly rewards careful study, and culminating in the coding of my first Python script from your example code. The **os.startfile (...)** method does indeed fire the browser!
For anyone interested:  **gdalogr:information** always calls _ogrinfo_ with the _-so_ (summary output) option. On the precept that too much information is better than too little, a cheap and dirty little fix is to edit ogrinfo.py and comment the line `arguments.append('-so')`.

Comment: @BadLoser Happy to help! If you're looking at Processing it's worth taking a look at the Graphical Modeler as well - it can be a lot easier than writing scripts if you only need to string together the Processing algorithms.

Comment: Great stuff. QGIS3 would be more like `processing.run('gdal:ogrinfo',{ 'INPUT' : lyr, 'NO_METADATA' : False, 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'SUMMARY_ONLY' : True })` It would be nice to pull the contents into a dict rather than pushing to a browser though.

Answer (score 0):

Update. The ogrinfo.exe **-so** option is now handled by ogrinfo.py, the python wrapper!

Example: Analysis of shape file with suppression of the **summary only** option

Start a QGIS project and open the Shape file of interest as a new vector layer.

Using Plugins/Python Console, create and run the following python script:

```
ipLayer = iface.activeLayer()
opHTML = 'C:\Users\DAZ\Desktop\shapeHTML.html'
import processing
import os
os.startfile(processing.runalg('gdalogr:information', ipLayer, 0, opHTML)["OUTPUT"])
```

Your browser gets fired and the full analysis becomes immediately visible. The **-so** option is controlled by the third parameter 0=full 1=summary