# Methods to more efficiently generate regularly spaced research points inside of a multipolygon

Tags: qgis, intersection, point-in-polygon, optimization

I'm currently using the tried-and-true, but extremely slow method of:

- via QGis, generating two (ESRI shapefiles) of a large number of research points over a multipolygon which are generated using a bounding box of the extremities of the multipolygon (a huge square shaped matrix of millions of points). This doesn't take that long.
- Then (also in QGis) running an intersection on the "raw" layer of research points on the actual multipolygon areas to output a layer of research points that only lie within multipolygon areas. Takes a very, very long time and seems very inefficient.

This still works well enough using sufficiently spaced out research points, but I'm now running an intersection of tens of millions of research points to output intersecting points totaling perhaps only 10,000. Its going to take over 8 hours* on my 16 core CPU. Is there a better way to do this (an optimized intersection operation) that won't cause too much brain damage?

*edit: took nearly 20 hours, and I know there's no way I used more than one core of my fancy processor. Arghh

Comment: OGR2OGR -clipsrclayer layer seems fairly fast to me.. What format is your data stored in? The storage format can make a big difference. How are you doing the intersection?

Comment: Its two rectilinear vector files (EPSG:3361) that I'm running the intersection on using QGis. The input layer is the massive layer of research points and the intersection layer is a multipolygon which is much, much smaller.

Comment: But what format? Esri Shapefile, CSV, MapInfo TAB... ?

Comment: They're in shapefile format

Comment: Shapefile is usually very fast, try OGR2OGR in some cases it's even faster than Esri clip. You could subset your points first using the extent of the layer with -clipsrc [xmin ymin xmax ymax] then extract just the points inside with another operation -clipsrclayer layer. If you're not comfortable with command line have a read of http://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/ogr2ogr/ and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165172/how-to-run-gdal-vector-ogr-tools-from-inside-qgis